# Compare two excel spreadsheets

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, comparison

I have a spreadsheet that is about 12 columns wide and 5k lines long.

I get a new sheet each week and I need to compare the two to determine

1. if a new line has been added
2. If an date in the delivery column has changed or been annotated as "delivered"

I do not have "view side by side" or the compare add-Inn.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SU. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a software solution like [Beyond Compare.](http://www.scootersoftware.com/)  This program will compare differences in folders, text, data (excel), Hex, MP3, and others.  It highlights the differences and you can merge the changes into either file from this program.